# Change picture by hovering over text

Tags: html, css

I want to change the displayed image, when the curosor is hovering over the `a` tag with plain css

My guess was to write something like this, but it didnt work:

```
.folder a:hover > .folder img{
    content: url(new picture);
}
```

here is my code

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="folder">
        <img></img>
        <a href="folder1">folder1</a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

css:

```
.folder img{
    content:url(pictures/folderdarkblue.png);
}
```

Comment: Images don't have `content`...and that not how an image tag looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be quite hard to do that using plain css with your current html code due to css not really allowing backward navigation. If you don't mind using the `<a>` after your image, you could try doing this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ksec65wm/

```
<div class="folder">
    <a href="folder1">folder1</a>
    <img class='one' src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png"/>
    <img class='two' src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img.one {
  display:none;
}
a:hover ~ img.one {
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover ~ img.two {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change picture on the hover of each individual div, why don't you try setting the opacity to 0, and then add the next picture?

Some hints

```
.box-container:hover .image-container,
.box-container:hover #picture {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Heres an example I found that is quite nice as well

https://jsfiddle.net/m4v1onyL/

The basic css goes as the following

```
a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}
a:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;  
}
a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;  
}
```

As you can see we just toggle between two images like this in an `<a>` tag.